# Gadget, Write Unicode Data in XML

Tags: xml, filesystemobject

I want in Gadget, Write Unicode data in XML File(I use UTF-8 to encode the XML document).

for Write to XML, Use " fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); ".

But after Write, data not Unicode.

In Addition, I need Data as Unicode.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

var objStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
objStream.Type = 2;//1=Binary Data , 2=Text Data(Default)
objStream.Open();
objStream.charset ="UTF-8";
objStream.WriteText(Data);
objStream.SaveToFile(System.Gadget.path + "\PhonebookContacts.xml",2);
//1=Creates a new file if the file does not already exist(Default)

//2=Overwrites the file with the data from the currently open Stream object, if the file already exists